# How to save every element in foreach and not just last element?

Tags: javascript, foreach

```
spliced.forEach((v) => {
    const val = v.split(',') //.slice(0, -2)
    formData.devID = val[0];
    formData.mobileno = val[1].slice(0, -1);

    //const cleanVal = [val[0], val[1].slice(0, -1)];
    req.body = formData;
    device.validate(formData, req.user, req.app.db.models, (error, result) => {
        let errorArr, resultArr = [];

        if (error) {
            errorArr.push(error)
        };

        if (result) {
            resultArr.push(result)
        };

        if (errorArr) {
            res.status(200).send({
                errors: [error]
            });
        } else {
            const formDataFull = new req.app.db.models.Device(formData);
            req.app.db.models.Device.bulkWrite([{
                        insertOne: {
                            formDataFull
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        ordered: false
                    }

                ])
                .then(function(device) {
                    console.log("created device err,", device);
                    workflow.emit('response');
                    res.status(200).send({
                        success: true
                    });

                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                    console.log("in catch err", err);
                    if (err.code == 11000) {
                        workflow.outcome.errors.push("Device Id already exists.");
                        return workflow.emit('response');
                    } else return workflow.emit('response', err);
                });
        }

    })
})
```

spliced is an array of CSV values. so in the above code, only the last object i.e. {formData} is saved. what way should i modify my code so that foreach saves every element and not just last.

Comment: isn't all the previous requests are cancelled as 6 connections are allowed AFAIK.

Comment: You're sending the response as soon as the first one was finished. Wait for all of them before you do that. Use `Promise.all` and `map` instead of `forEach`

Comment: @Jai i didnt understand this, could you please elaborate. thank you

Comment: @bergi okay let me try that.

Comment: You should declare formData as const inside the foreach block

Comment: @tano okay let me try this too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so this problem was solved simply by using for-loop. Some people answered using loops and map but sadly none of it worked for me. Maybe my code implementation was wrong. Nevertheless using simple for loop saved the day. thank you all.

PS. This can work if you use a counter to track the callbacks and doing the computation after counter equals the number of parameters in callback.